# Proper Way to Enqueue CSS for Front Page - template_redirect in functions.php?

Tags: template-redirect

I want to load some specific css to change color of body element of front/home page of WP. Within my themes function file, the following code seems to work, but can someone please tell me if it is "proper"?

```
//Adding and Encuing styles for Front Page
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'front_page_design' );

function front_page_design(){
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home()) {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_index_styles');
        function enqueue_index_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'home_page_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/index-style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home_page_style' );
        }
    }
}
```

I had come across a [blog by Mark Jaquith](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/) saying that template_include is for including, which is what I'm doing, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook directly for enqueing all styles and scripts. There's no need to hook into `template_include` for that. `template_include` is specifically for modifying templates.

```
//Adding and Encuing styles for Front Page
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_page_design' );

function front_page_design(){
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home_page_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/index-style.css', array('handle_of_main_style') );
    }
}
```

Where 'name_of_main_style' must be changed to match the handle of the stylesheet you want to load 'home_page_style` after.

Comment: Ninja-fast! Should be working but am recovering from the soccer match.

Comment: Yes! I had been trying to use `if ( is_front_page() || is_home())` before `add_action`, which of course didn't work because `$wp_query` object has been set up with the current page yet. But it DOES work within a function! However - doing it the above way, most of my css is being overridden by the parent template template css unless I add !important.

Comment: You can add a `$dependecy` argument to [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) so that it is always enqueued after your parent stylesheet. See edit.

Comment: Struggling a little to FIND the handle of the css file I want to override...

Comment: To identify the `handle` I'm trying to load after, I first tried using the `id` names. Then searched the theme files for the base name of the parent templates css file. Then searched the parent theme files for `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`. The handle is the item between quotes  in something like this, right `wp_enqueue_style('tc-customizer-controlsstyle'`?

Comment: Yes, 'tc-customizer-controlsstyle' would be the handle. For example in the markup: `<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-pagenavi-css'  href='http://www.kathyisawesome.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-pagenavi/pagenavi-css.css?ver=2.70' type='text/css' media='all' />` the handle would be "wp-pavenavi"

Comment: Is the `id` always going to be the `handle-name` with `-css` appended to it?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that is the standard behavior.

Comment: Weird. Is it considered more eloquent not to `register` a script or style if you are only enqueuing it one time?

Comment: My take on it is that if you are loading it on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook there isn't really a need to write the two out separately. If however, you need to make a decision at a later time it is ok to register it and then call `wp_enqueue_script($handle)` at a later point... I think that's more of an issue for scripts though.

Comment: @helgatheviking the $dependency actually needs to be an array as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style. Would you update answer to reflect `wp_enqueue_style( 'home_page_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/index-style.css', array('name_of_main_style') );` before I accept?

Comment: Good catch. Done.

Answer (score 1):

When enqueueing scripts and styles, you **should be using** the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook to hook your scripts and styles to

> `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for enqueuing both scripts and styles.

The use of [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) and [`template_includes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) is totally wrong.

It is always good practice that if you load your own scripts and styles, to load them last to ensure that your scripts and styles does not get overridden by others. To do that, you must set your `$priority` parameter in [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) very low (very high number). I just always make this `999`

You should either do this

```
function front_page_design(){
if ( is_front_page() || is_home()) {
    wp_register_style( 'home_page_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/index-style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'home_page_style' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_page_design', 999);
```

or this

```
function front_page_design(){
    wp_register_style( 'home_page_style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/index-style.css' );
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home_page_style' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_page_design', 999);
```

Comment: The function `enqueue_index_styles` doesn't exist in your examples??

Comment: I think `if ( is_front_page() || is_home())` returns false within functions.php unless it is within a function. And I think in the above examples `enqueue_index_styles` would be replaced with `front_page_design` - or the opposite.

Comment: @helgatheviking Copy and paste error. That is what happens if you try to answer one more question, and you should actually have been in bed. :-) Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @MikeiLL silly copy and paste error. I've updated my answer. Check if it works now

Comment: Figured as much. Have done it myself. :)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I imagine it will work, however based on the answer from helga the viking, realized adding a dependency was necessary. And sadly I don't yet have the credentials to even give your answer a bump. Thank you very much, though for the thorough response.

Comment: It is just great to know that my answer helped you. I would however like to ask you, if helga's answer did the trick, accept her answer by clicking on the check mark next to her answer

Comment: I had just asked her to update one part of the code that had listed a string where an array was expected - in the dependency segment of the statement. : )